# How to split a C++ project into two in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

### Scenario 1

A solution `SolA` contains only 1 project named `PrjA`.
`PrjA` is a Win32 console application, the compilation result is `PrjA.exe`.

How shall I split the source code files in `PrjA` into `PrjA1` and `PrjB`, so that the management of the source code is easier, while the compilation result, `PrjA1.exe`, will be almost the same as `PrjA.exe`?

For example, I have `PrjA` :-

- `PrjA` has 300 `.cpp` files.
- `PrjA.exe` sizes 400KB.

I hope to split `PrjA` into 2 projects :-

- `PrjA1` has 200 `.cpp` files
- `PrjB` has 100 `.cpp` files.
- `PrjA1.exe` is also around 400KB.

I'm not sure how to setup `PrjB` or what will be its compilation result.
Assume `PrjB` compiles to `PrjB.DLL`, sized 100KB, I hope `PrjA1.exe` will somehow embed `PrjB.dll` inside itself.  Thus the size would be 400KB.
I don't want a 300KB `PrjA1.exe`, which will dynamically link to 100KB `PrjB.dll` in runtime.

**Question:** How shall I set `PrjB`, and how shall I set the link between `PrjA1` and `PrjB`?

### Scenario 2

Same as Scenario 1, just this round `PrjA`'s compilation result is a windows DLL, named `PrjA.dll`, how shall I split `PrjA` into `PrjA1` and `PrjB`?

The development environment is Visual Studio 2013 under windows 7 64-bits, but the compilation results are 32-bit.

Comment: It is not clear at all what you are asking:
>How shall I split ProjA int PrjA1 and PrjB,so that the compilation result, PrjA1.exe, will be almost the same as PrjA.exe?

Comment: @TomasZubiri thx. I just updated the question

Comment: It still is not clear what splitting means. If prjA splits into PrjA1 and PrjB , but PrjA1 produces the same output. What would PrjB contain? Wouldn't PrjA1 contain all of prjA?

Comment: @TomasZubiri what split is the source code files, but I hope the compilation result, the exe file remains almost the same after the code split.

Comment: You should probably create a proof-of-concept test project, where you have just two or three source files, which you then have in separate projects under the solution. Generally, not Visual Studio or Windows specific, you will have application projects which produce the executables, and library projects with shared code, which produce (static or shared) library files. An executable project will not use code from other executable projects, only from other library projects.

Comment: But it is unclear what you are actually asking. Is it, "How do I organize my project", or "How do I use Visual Studio"?

Comment: @hyde I assume you are referring to scenario 1, hinting that PrjA1 shall be the same win32 console application project, and PrjB is a library project? Then... how to do config so? And how shall I config prjA1 as sharing code with PrjB?

Comment: @hyde how shall I use visual studio to organize my project -- I don't use notepad

Comment: You may add new static library project, move all business logic there and then reference it in solution explorer. Whether this is easily done depends on your application architecture. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: @DmitryKuznetsov yes. How shall I config these two projects ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how you move existing code into static library. I use VS2015, it should be the same with VS2013, but I can't check that. I start with the following solution structure:
[image: Initial solution structure, all code in one project]

First thing to do is to add new project to the solution.
`File -> Add -> New project -> Win32 Project`

Check Static library and uncheck precompiled header
[image: Win32 Application wizard]

Then click Show all files icon in the solution explorer for both projects. This turn filters off and shows project folder as it is. It should look like this:
[image: Solution explorer shows files in project folders]

Drag and drop all needed files from one project to another:
[image: Project structure after relocation]

Now  reference your library. Uncheck Show all files icon to show References. `Right click -> Add reference` and check your static library project:
[image]
[image]

Last thing to do is to add include directory to the project that uses the library. This is done in project properties. Be sure to check All configurations and All platforms:
[image]

That's it. Now when you build your solution, VS builds your static library, builds your main project and links them together. The result should be identical as if everything is in the same project.